# node socket.io not working using VPN

Tags: node.js

Everything's work fine on localhost but when I place it to live server some user's can't read my socket, even I use VPN my socket stop having an error (GET http://websitedomain.com:9090/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LktMvZ3 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT) even I use 0.0.0.0 in port still not working

Server.js

```
var socket  = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = socket.listen(server);
var port    = process.env.PORT || 9090;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('connected')
})

server.listen(port, 'website-ip', function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});
```

App.js

```
socket = io.connect('http://'+window.location.hostname+':9090');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to add a reverse proxy like Nginx so you can establish the connection through port 80? Some systems/firewalls probably have blocked that port.